# How to get image from HTTP-auth protected area?

Tags: php, http-authentication

I have a web-camera(D-LINK DCS-2130) and a web-site. Camera haven't "guest" option(or I haven't found where is it?), that so I need to authorize my site to show image from cam. What is a correct way to display an image?

I have 2 ideas:

1. Create getImage.php, which will send login+pass(cURL) to the camera and
   get the image. In my site's code I'll use `src="getImage.php"`
2. Create same getImage.php, which will send login+pass(cURL), get the image, store it localy into `/myCameraSnapshots/Image.jpg` `wait()` 1 second, then get new image and overwrite it localy.

The first way will do many requests to the camera (1 viewer — 1 request), second will get load my server's CPU, but will not disturb camera's authorization.

I hope You can say "You're an idiot! There's a easy way to get image from protected folder! Just do..." ;)

Comment: i don't understand the second option.

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel authorize once and get and get and get and get image from camera, store it localy, use on site's code local image

Comment: what does it mean "authorize once"?

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel I can authorize once via my script, it'll save cookies, after that i'll restrict my script to end using `wait()` function and just get image, store it, wait 1 sec, get image, store it, etc. Yes, I can set max_execution_time for my scripts to one hour for example, set crontab to restart this script every hour. This way I'll have 1 php process on my server.

Comment: I see no sense in this way. It is exactly as the first one, but it will actually spam your camera with requests every second, no matter if someone actually watching it or not.

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel is way to send 100+ request per second to authorize+get_image is better?

Comment: well, if you have that much viewers - no. However, your idea of "authorize once" still makes no sense. In fact, you have to authorize every time you are getting an image. Cookie or POST data -it doesn't matter, you have to send them with every request and thus "dusturb" your camera authorization anyway. It is not a big deal though.

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel just want to make +10 for You. Can You post Your answer?

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel I've found that I can use `http://<user>:<password>@<host>:<port>/<url-path>` in my URL to automate auth. I needn't cURL more in this task :)

Comment: You can't I believe. browsers will ask user to enter a password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are doing proper authorization in `getImage.php`, the second method (using a cache) will likely be more efficient.

If `getImage.php` uses a `Content-Type` header, then simply place `/myCameraSnapshots` out of the web server root (or restrict it to local access only), and then use `readfile` as needed to dump the contents when called.

Depending on how often the image(s) on the camera change, you will need a method to invalidate the cached image as well (perhaps by deleting it), which should prompt `getImage.php` to request it again from the camera.

Comment: Is there no way to do it more "beautiful"? :( Camera have timestamp on image and I can't(it should always stay) remove it, that so I'll call new image every second any way..

Answer (score 0):

I've found guest's password for this camera (guest:guest), so my problem solved, but anyway everyone should to read answers, in them You can find answers to **Your** questions!